What is the expected distribution of fracture points for a uniform elastomer?
I'm trying to think about what kind of distribution should I expect, theoretically, for the fracture point of an elastic material with respect to its length. Let's say for example that I'm holding a piece of rubber band of length $L$ and overall uniform density $\rho$ from its end points, $A$ and $B$, and then I start stretching it beyond its elastic and plastic regimes until it snaps. I write down the location of the fracture point for this experiment, say $\ell= L_A/L$. If I repeat the experiment many times, what would be my expected distribution for $\ell$, assuming everything is ideal (perhaps even ignoring the pinching due to holding the rubber band at each end). Should it be a uniform distribution, or a Gaussian distribution centered at the middle point, with its standard deviation depending on the material? I'm not sure I can think of other possibilities given the symmetry of the problem.

In practice, the results would be very sensitive to the end clamping conditions; that's one reason why dogbone shapes are used in tensile testing—to ensure that additional stresses from clamping don't produce a stress state that exceeds that in the middle region of smaller cross-sectional area:

Ignoring this aspect, assuming the loading is tensile only, and assuming manufacturing defects aren't concentrated anywhere, say, the tensile stress $\sigma=\frac{F}{A}$ is modelled as being constant down the segment of cross-sectional area $A$ exposed to load $F$. Thus, the expected distribution of initial failure points is also uniform along that section. In other words, there's nothing special about the center that would preferentially induce failure there unless you make it special (by both stretching and bending the bar in a way that would maximize the stress there, for example—though anyone who's tried to snap a strand of uncooked spaghetti at the exact middle knows that's not trivial either).
